# Typescript mad with using rest props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

If I have a component,

```
import { FC } from 'react';

interface Props {
  name: string;
}

const Home: FC<Props> = ({ name, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{name}</div>
      <input {...rest} type="text" />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

and try to use it like `<Home name="testName" placeholder="test" />`, my editor is mad giving red underline under `placeholder`.

Raw Error:

```
Type '{ name: string; placeholder: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'placeholder' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

I tried extending the Props with HTMLAttributes but it didn't work.

```
interface Props extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What is FC?
   It's a React functional component definition, which by default has `children?: ReactNode` interface defined which can be extended.
2. You are trying to define `props` for your component.
   In your use case You provided `const Home: FC<Props>`. This means, You've extended the interface of `React.FC` with your `Props` definition. This means that you have
   `{children: ReactNode, name: string}` described to typescript as valid parameters that you are expecting. 
   **This means** if you pass something else, that is not defined in the interface, You will get an error.
   **In Your case** You are destructuring the parameters:
   `name,...rest`. From Your interface definition this means, that `...rest` will be only the property - `children` , because that's what You defined in your interface.\
3. While the simplest solution to solve Your error would be only to introduce a new property in your interface called placeholder, a better solution would be to provide an interface, that would match your `...rest` spread operator. Since all of Your props go inside of button, you can extend your Props interface with `React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>`.

```
interface Props extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  name: string;
}

const Home: FC<Props> = ({ name, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{name}</div>
      <input {...rest} type="text" />
    </>
  );
};
```

Update:
A `VSCODE` trick on inspecting what types does an element, or its property has is to simply hover on it.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the types React comes with inbuilt. Do you know any site where common React inbuilt types are listed?

Comment: I think there is a site. But it's not much help. What You can do is use your IDE for that.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the rest operator.

> ```
> interface Props {
>   name: string;
> }
> ```

Your interface doesn't allow a `placeholder` attribute on the element.

If you want to pass through properties allowed on an input, then you have to include those properties on the interface.

```
interface Props extends React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"input"> {
  name: string;
}
```